# Paste one column to another with NA conditional

Tags: r, conditional-statements, paste, na

I would like to paste `col3` to `col1` however avoiding `NAs` in `col1`.

My input:

```
df <- "col1 col2 col3
       100   x   102
       105   x   106
       101   x   NA"
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

My expected output:

```
dfout <- "col1 col2 col3
       102   x   102
       106   x   106
       101   x   NA"
dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `df$col1[!is.na(df$col3)] <- na.omit(df$col3)`?

Comment: @user2120870 Is your `dfout` correct ? You stated you would like `col3` pasted to `col1` but that is not the case in `dfout`

Comment: Sorry @steveb, I can´t see were is the error. The only difference that I am seeing between those two collumns in dfout is the NA, which was not pasted (actually my original problem).

Comment: @user2120870 I misread your question so I think this is done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the sounds of it, something like the following should do what you describe:

```
df$col1[!is.na(df$col3)] <- na.omit(df$col3)
```

Alternatively, but following the same concept, would be:

```
df$col1 <- replace(df$col1, !is.na(df$col3), na.omit(df$col3))
```

Comment: Another variation is `transform(df, col1 = ifelse(is.na(col3), col1, col3))`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table` and assign (`:=`) in place which can be more efficient.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(col3), col1:= col3]
df
#  col1 col2 col3
#1:  102    x  102
#2:  106    x  106
#3:  101    x   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse()`:

```
df$col1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$col3), df$col1, df$col3)
```

This can also be used together with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, col1 = ifelse(is.na(col3), col1, col3))
```